# Passport local strategy doesnt return user

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-local

My signup and login works completely fine until I want to return user to the front end. User ends up being undefined.

Here is my passport.js

```
const passport = require('passport');
const localStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const User = mongoose.model('users');

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user._id)
})


passport.deserializeUser((id, done) =>
    User.findById(id).then((user) => {
        if (user) {
            done(null, user)
        } else {
        }
    })
);

passport.use(new localStrategy((username, password, done) => {
    User.findOne({ username: username }, (err, user) => {
        console.log(user)
        if (err) { return done(err); }

        if (!user) {
            return done(null, false, { message: 'Username not found' });
        }

        if (!user.comparePassword(password, user.password)) {
            return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
        }

        return done(null, user);
    });
}));
```

Here is my login route:

```
const passport = require('passport');

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const User = mongoose.model('users');

module.exports = (app) => {
    app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
        res.send('elo')
    })

    app.post('/login',
        passport.authenticate('local', {
            successRedirect: '/loginSuccess',
            failureRedirect: '/loginFailed',
        })
    );

    app.get('/loginSuccess', (req, res) => {
        console.log(req.user)
        res.send({ success: true, test:'test', user: req.user })
    })
    app.get('/loginFailed', (req, res) => {
        res.send({ success: false, error: "Incorrect credentials" })
    })
};
```

In passport.js the user exists and should be returnet correctly. It's just getting lost somewhere along the way. Whats funnier, I used the exact same code in my other app few months ago and it worked properly.

Edit:
Turns out it works on postman, so I dont know whats going on now

Comment: "it works on postman, but not elsewhere": it smells like like HTTP requests are CORS-blocked in your script, but not in Postman. But that's just my intuition.

Comment: I installed libraries to handle cors problems, so thats not it.
But I ended up setting proxy in my app and suddenly it works now. Although I dont get why

Comment: I suggest that the correct behavior for `it works and I don't get why` would still be to write an answer, in case someone is facing the same issue :)